# Handle Files ( in this case video) inside ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, api

I have a problem with my Backend guy on an API response. he added a function for downloading files from server and it checks two headers of ajax request with the file url , if they matches,it will send the video in the response of the request, by other mean :

url: url of VIDEO files
Type: GET
Header: {HEader1 : 1 , Header2: 2 }

Response: NOTHING BUT A SINGLE "video file"

Question 1: GENERALLY how to handle FILES inside the response of ajax request?
Question 2: In this case how to HANDLE this VIDEO file? ( play it inside a frame? open it in new tab? open a tab with desired headers so browser can show the video? or how to extract it from the response boy?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I think below data would be suffice:
CODE:

```
{var requestUrl = "URL/9b734_fe9e6673ee.mp4";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: requestUrl,
    headers: {
        SOME HEADERS
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("done")
        console.log(response)
        //The Response is a video file

    },
    error: function(response, data) {
        alert("error!!")
        console.log(response)
        console.log(data)
    }
})
}
```

Response as attachment:[Response inside Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6SPu.jpg)
{
 - done
- ��� ftypisom����isomiso2avc1mp41����free�q��mdat!0����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������0{���5����1�E���H��,� �#��x264 - core 118 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=dia subme=0 psy=0 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=8 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=14 keyint_min=1 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=abr mbtree=0 bitrate=440 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=10 qpmax=51 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0������e�������P���������x�rg�������h�׎:#_I�ɩ95&.#^�����.%���ȿ��7>H������[�/��-�7��D���O���n#��NN#^���w�ߗ���X…
}

Comment: What is the type of video file?

Comment: Can you share the response screenshot from the chrome developer tools window?

Comment: Question Edited